# Why is browser loading CSS/JS/img assets in unexpected order (not the order of HTML source)?

Tags: html, browser, shopify, assets, core-web-vitals

**My understanding**

So my understanding is, if you have a website with the following source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script-head.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <img width="400" src="image.jpg" />
    <script src="script-closing.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

...the browser will queue the assets to be loaded in the following order (the order they appear in the page source):

1. style.css
2. script-head.js
3. image.jpg
4. script-closing.js

I have tested this simple HTML page in Chrome Dev Tools Network tab and the assets do load in that order.

[image: Network tab listing assets in order expected.]

All makes sense to me. So far so good.

**The confusion**

But in practice, I'm working on optimising the [Largest Contentful Paint](https://web.dev/lcp/) score of a website (if at all relevant, though I don't know how/why if we are just talking about page load, it's a Shopify website...). So I need to load the largest image on the screen quickly. And the loading isn't happening as I expect.

If we take this site as an example (this is not actually the site I am working on, but it seems to be happening on all the "larger" sites I've assessed. This one is Shopify too): https://www.luxyhair.com/

It has images (eg. //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0066/0052/files/Homepage-Hero_1x1_Cool-Dark-Brown-Balayage_800x.jpg?v=1632412052) that are queued in the Network tab ***after*** JS scripts that are below it in the page source (eg. //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0066/0052/t/207/assets/theme.min.js?v=18003517125669543370).

I'm not sure why this is happening.

[image: luxyhair.com Network tab]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ....
        <link href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0066/0052/t/207/assets/theme.min.css?v=10166822434284191108" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        ....
    </head>
    <body class="theme-index">
        ....
        <img class="one-whole" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0066/0052/files/Homepage-Hero_1x1_Cool-Dark-Brown-Balayage_800x.jpg?v=1632412052" alt="" />
        ....
        <script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0066/0052/t/207/assets/theme.min.js?v=18003517125669543370" type="text/javascript"></script>
        ....
    </body>
</html>
```

My fundamental confusion here is why the browser is queuing assets not in the order they are listed in the HTML source.

**How I can get an image to load before a bunch of JS scripts that are in the footer that aren't as important?** I know about `<link rel="preload">` but I can't use that as the image is defined in a page section that's not available for me to capture until after the `<head>` of the page (because of how Shopify's section templating engine works). I've tried inserting a `<link rel="preload">` into the  with an inline script, but as expected that hasn't worked. I have also tried adding [`importance="high"`](https://web.dev/priority-hints/) on the img tag. That also hasn't worked.

Comment: Note that using `importance=high` is an experimental API that's only currently available via an [origin trial in Chrome](https://web.dev/priority-hints/#origin-trial) in Chrome. In other words, you have to sign up for the origin trial before you'll see it working.

Comment: @PhilipWalton Yes, realised after I posted that this feature hadn't been shipped yet!